# strptime() function is undefined

Tags: php, datetime, strptime

I have a strange problem with `strptime()` function.

There is no php extension installation required in php manual and it is available in **PHP 5 >= 5.1.0**. I have installed wamp server on windows seven with **php 5.3.5**. but when I call this function it returns a fatal error which says `function strptime is undefined`. I can't understand what is problem. Is this func available in win7?

Comment: Nopes! Not in Windows platforms!

Comment: Not a real question?! Stack overflow, I love you but you drive me nuts sometimes. This is a clear question with a simple answer. Yes, it comes from not reading the docs fully but so do most other questions.

Answer (score 17):

> Is this func available in win7?

[From the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php)

> ```
> Note: This function is not implemented on Windows platforms.
> ```